# node module babel-preset-es2015 large number of files - Laravel application

Tags: babeljs, node-modules

I have a laravel 5.3 installation which has over 130,000 files in it (it is not a particularly large application either!). This seems like quite a lot and is causing issues with syncing via Box Sync.

I noticed that over 75,000 of the files are from the node babel-preset-es2015 folder and I was wondering whether this was normal or not? It seems like a lot to me?

Thanks